# Trigger a button click with jQuery when enter button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, enter

This is jQuery code of mine.instead of using proceed button when i click on enter remaining text boxes should display

```js
$("#btnValidateMember").click(function () {
  if ($("#txtUserEmail").val() == "") {
    $("#txtUserEmail").addClass("error");
    //$("#spnUserEmail").text("required");
  }
  else if($("#spnUserEmail").text() == "")
  {
    GetMemberDetailsbasedonEmailId($("#txtUserEmail").val());
  }
  $("#ddlBusinessState").empty().append($("<option/>"));
  //$("#ddlBusinessCity").empty().append($("<option/>"));
  $("#ddlBusinessState").select2({ placeholder: 'State', allowClear: false });
  //$("#ddlBusinessCity").select2({ placeholder: 'City', allowClear: false, width: '366px' });
  BindStatesBasedOnCountryId("1",`enter code here` "ddlBusinessState", "");enter code here

});
```

Comment: Do you mean hitting on enter button will trigger the click on `#btnValidateMember`?

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("#textbox").on('keydown', function(e) {
  const ENTER_KEY_CODE = 13;
  const ENTER_KEY = "Enter"
  var keycode = e.keyCode || e.which;
  var key = e.key;
  if (keycode == ENTER_KEY_CODE || key == ENTER_KEY) {
    document.querySelector("#BtnValidateMember").click();
  }
});
```

```css
.button {
  padding: 15px 25px;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 9px #999;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: #3e8e41
}

.button:active {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
  box-shadow: 0 5px #666;
  transform: translateY(4px);
}

#textbox {
  border-radius: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="BtnValidateMember" class="button" onclick="alert('Button Pressed')">Button</button>
<input type="search" id="textbox">
```

Comment: Stop using `which` and `keyCode`. We're humans. Use `Event.key`.

Comment: How about we use `e.which | | e.keyCode | | e.key` | | is `or` so javascript gets to decide `which` one to use

Answer (score 0):

Please see this [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/biveboloju/edit?html,js,output)

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        $('#btnValidateMember').trigger('click');
    }
});
```

Above `jQuery` code will detect the keypress event 
If you have pressed enter button it will trigger the click event of `#btnValidateMember` button.

Comment: OK, 13, but do you know by memory what key is 122? No? Neither do I. Use `Event.key`.

Comment: 122 is f11 key. Use this https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/javascript-keycodes/

Comment: No. I don't need any table for `Event.key`

Comment: @Roko `Event.key` is not supported by Firefox and Internet Explorer

Comment: @JustinLiu can you please report it here? https://caniuse.com/#feat=keyboardevent-key

Comment: @JustinLiu Can you open this one in Firefox and try it out? https://jsfiddle.net/8pb4c90x/

Comment: developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key It show that before firefox version 22 `Event.key` is not supported